# confused about what must be escaped for sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace specific strings in php files automatically using sed. Some work, and some do not. I already investigated this is not an issue with the replacement string but with the string that is to be replaced. I already tried to escape [ and ] with no success. It seems to be the whitespace within the () - not whitespaces in general. The first whitespaces (around the = ) do not have any problems. Please can someone point me to the problem:

`sed -e "1,\$s/$adm = substr($path . rawurlencode($upload['name']) ,  16);/$adm = rawurlencode($upload['name']); # fix 23/g" -i administration/identify.php`

I already tried to shorten the string which should be replaced and the result was if I cut it directly behind $path it works, with the following whitespace it does not. Escaping whitespace has no effect...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your input and expected output

Comment: you don't need `1,$` as address range as that is the default... use single quotes instead of double quotes around the sed expression unless `$adm`, `$path`, etc are all bash variables?

Comment: you'd need to escape `[` character, and use `\x27` where single quotes are needed, for example, `\x27name\x27`

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\$adm = substr(\$path \. rawurlencode(\$upload\['"'"'name'"'"']) ,  16);/$adm = rawurlencode($upload['"'"'name'"'"']); # fix 23/g' administration/identify.php`

Comment: nothing of this are bash variables - all has to be interpreted as plain text

Comment: this works: sed -e "s/$adm = substr($path/..... and this does not work: sed -e "s/$adm = substr($path /.... this does not work, too: sed -e "s/$adm = substr($path\ /.... and replacing whitepsace after $path with /s does not work, too. It seems to be a problem with the whitespace following $path (maybe not the only issue)

Comment: Does `path` contain `/` characters?

Comment: If my answer lacks something please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

> what must be escaped for sed

The following characters have special meaning in `sed` and have to be escaped with `\` for the regex to be taken literally:

- `\`
- `[`
- the character used in separating `s` command parts, ie. `/` here
- `.`
- `*`
- `&` only replacement string

Newline character is handled specially as the end of the string, but can be replaced for `\n`.

So first escape all special characters in input and then pass it to sed:

```
rgx="$adm = substr($path . rawurlencode($upload['name']) ,  16);"
rgx_escaped=$(sed 's/[\\\[\.\*\/&]/\\&/g' <<<"$rgx")
sed "s/$rgx_escaped/ etc."
```

See [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) for a generic escaping solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sed -i 's/\$adm = substr(\$path \. rawurlencode(\$upload\['"'"'name'"'"']) , 16);/$adm = rawurlencode($upload['"'"'name'"'"']); # fix 23/g' administration/identify.php
```

Note:

- the `sed` command is basically wrapped in single quotes, the variable expansion won't occur inside single quotes
- In the POSIX BRE syntax, `(` matches a literal `(`, you do not need to escape `)` either, but you need to escape `[` and `.` that must match themselves
- The single quotes require additional quoting with concatenation.